# Python Pandas - drop duplicates from dataframe and merge the columns value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge, duplicates

I am trying to remove duplicates from my Dataframe and save their data into the columns where they are NA/Empty.

Example:
I've the following DATAFRAME and I would like to remove all the duplicates in column A but merge the values from the rest of the tables

| A | B | C | D | E |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | X |  |  |  |
| 2 | X |  |  |  |
| 2 |  | X |  |  |
| 2 |  |  | X |  |
| 3 |  | X |  |  |
| 3 |  |  | X |  |
| 2 |  |  |  | X |

The expected output:

| A | B | C | D | E |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | X |  |  |  |
| 2 | X | X | X | X |
| 3 |  | X | X |  |

How can I perform the above dynamically?

Thanks in advance for the answers

Comment: not sure what is to merge, but seem like drop_duplicates would do what you need..

Comment: @Darmon, just use `df.groupby("A", as_index=False).first()`.

Comment: @Timeless - It didn't work for me, but I managed to resolve it with the code below

Comment: @JeJe - Merge, means I need to keep the values for the rest of the columns, drop_duplicates just delete them

Comment: @Darmon I see, so groupBy prob what you need as suggested, you prob need to check what you want to do if/when there are multiple datas in b,c,d,e for a given a...

Comment: @Timeless your answer eventually worked for me, but I needed to assign it to a new value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`groupby_first`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.first.html) because it *compute the first non-null entry of each column.*:

```
>>> df.groupby('A', as_index=False).first()
   A     B     C     D     E
0  1     X  None  None  None
1  2     X     X     X     X
2  3  None     X     X  None
```

Comment: I don't receive the same output as you do, when I do

Comment: I reused your dataframe constructor from your answer. Are you sure you have None and not an empty string?

Comment: Apology, I didn't assign the "groupby_first" to a different value so that is why it didn't change, but it is working for me now. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Managed to achieve this by grouping the DataFrame by column A, and then aggregating the values of the other columns using a custom function that concatenates the non-null values

Here is the code:

```
import pandas as pd

# Define a custom function to concatenate non-null values
def concat_non_null(x):
    return ' '.join(filter(lambda v: pd.notnull(v), x))

# Define the DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'A': [1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 2],
    'B': ['X', 'X', None, None, None, None, None],
    'C': [None, None, 'X', None, 'X', None, None],
    'D': [None, None, None, 'X', None, 'X', None],
    'E': [None, None, None, None, None, None, 'X']
})

# Group the DataFrame by column A and aggregate the other columns using the custom function
df_agg = df.groupby('A').agg({
    'B': concat_non_null,
    'C': concat_non_null,
    'D': concat_non_null,
    'E': concat_non_null
}).reset_index()

# Print the result
print(df_agg)
```